# Selenium: How to click a button using the button label?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In the HTML code like this:

```
<a class="test-class">
    <div class="test-content">
        <div class="test-time" data-start="12:13pm" data-full="12:13 PM - 12:50 PM">
            <span>12:13pm - 12:50pm</span>
        </div>
        <div class="test-title">Classes Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="test-bg"></div>
</a>
```

I am trying to click `<a class="test-class"">`. However, I need to locate that element by text `12:13pm - 12:50pm` from `<span>12:13pm - 12:50pm</span>` , which is not visible from front-end.

Is there a way to get XPath of `<a class="test-class"">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the "a" element you would need to use *ancestor*

```
//span[text()='12:13pm - 12:50pm']/ancestor::a[@class='test-class']
```

Comment: Cool! It works for me! Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As per the code shared above, any of the following two `x-paths` can be used to locate the element by using the text mentioned in the question.

*To search element by exact text:*

> ```
>  //a[@class='test-class']//span[text()='12:13pm - 12:50pm']
> ```

*or*

Below x-path is for like search. This will give you flexibility to use unique part of the text

(in case, there are multiple elements with similar text).

> ```
> //a[@class='test-class']//span[contains(text(),'12:13pm - 12:50pm')]
> ```

Comment: Thx for your help. But when i try to use this xpath, i am not able to locate the element as it is not visible. As i mentioned in the question, the text is not visible for front-end, i think it might be the reason. But @George McConnon 's answer works for me.

Comment: Sorry mate. But, I am glad that the other answer worked for you and your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with above answers. Wanted to add few points:

> Solution 1 -

- This solution is working currently with me.

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[. = '12:13pm - 12:50pm']")).click();
  ```
- But its has one barrier. Can't user for other than english's some special characters. Avoided in next solution 2

> Solution 2 -

- This is good fit solution if you are using string or text with special characters, white spaces.

  ```
  String label = "12:13pm - 12:50pm";
  String string = String.format("//button[contains(.,'%s')]", label);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(string));
  ```
- I got solution from [here](https://goo.gl/MiySAv)