# Selenium Webdriver: HOW TO CLICK IN A BUTTON WITHIN A CLASS OVER OTHER CLASS?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I've been trying to click in a button and haven't succeeded.
I want to access **line 130** ***Começa a new game***

[image: line 130 "Começa a new game"]

It has two elements with class=*"responsive-lg"* and the one I want is the second.

I need help to overcome that!
I've tried:

- [Selenium: How to click a button using the button label?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/selenium-how-to-click-a-button-using-the-button-label)
- [How to click Image icon using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753629/how-to-click-image-icon-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: What's the issue you facing and also add the html as code not inage

Comment: I've already overcome the "such" problem, n also did not know that is  forbidden post images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your search criteria is the text, you can use XPath:

```
"//*[text()='Começa a new game']"
```

Comment: Thanks. It Works.

Comment: I also fount other way: `link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='p-5']/div[4]/button[1]")))`